# Why does angular date filter adding 2 to hour?

Tags: angularjs

I've created a duration timer in angular js, using angular 'date' filter.
For some reason, the hour part starting with '2' instead of '0'.

I'm using the filter like this

```
 {{runningDuration | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpg2kill/vNdpu/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run the JSFiddle, the hour starts with 0, not 2.

Comment: I've checked on I.E., Crome and FireFox with four computers. The problem is still exist. Do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: I'm just guessing ... maybe it could be something with the timezone.

Comment: isn't it just a locale/timezone issue ? When I look at it, it starts with 1h, if you change your format to `date:'HH:mm:ss Z'` I think you will see something like -0200 after the time, which would mean you are in UTC time, I'm on -0100, and I think some people in Australia should have -1000

Comment: You are right, it is the timezone. Is there a way to use the 'date' filter without the the local timezone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you want to format a date but pass it a *difference between dates as an integer*. Angular then assumes you want `new Date(runningDuration)`.

You can use a filter to convert the date to utc(this probably requires more corner case handling than just number and date). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vNdpu/9/)

**JS**

```
myApp.filter('utc', [function() {
    return function(date) {
      if(angular.isNumber(date)) {
        date = new Date(date);
      }
      return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
    }   
  } ]);
```

**HTML**

```
{{runningDuration | utc | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}
```