# Ignore Time Zone Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Is there a better way to ignore an timezone in Angularjs:

"2014-01-18 14:30:00"  Instead Of "2014-01-18 15:30:00"

```
function Scoper($scope) {
    $scope.datum = "2014-01-18T14:30:00Z";
}

<div ng:app ng:controller="Scoper">
    DateTime  <br />
    Angular: {{datum | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}} <br />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samibel/2rMXJ/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this answer: [Why does angular date filter adding 2 to hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121782/why-does-angular-date-filter-adding-2-to-hour)

Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/OQAdEFI/3/edit):

#### Just pipe another filter:

```js
app.filter('utc', function(){

  return function(val){
    var date = new Date(val);
     return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), 
                     date.getUTCMonth(), 
                     date.getUTCDate(),  
                     date.getUTCHours(), 
                     date.getUTCMinutes(), 
                     date.getUTCSeconds());
  };    

});
```

#### In your template:

```html
<span>{{ date | utc | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}</span>
```

Comment: Since version ```1.3.0``` AngularJS supports ```UTC``` timezone as an extra filter parameter for dates. And since version ```1.4.0-rc.0``` it supports other timezones too. So with newer AngularJS versions preferred solution will be the one suggested by @DanielM

Comment: I've tried using the UTC feature on the updated angular but it was still showing the wrong date. This custom filter worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

I was experimenting the same problem for a while. There is a timezone possible parameter to the date filter which I think should be the preferred solution, instead of making your own filter and append it. So, this is what worked for me:

```
{{ someAcceptedDateFormat | date : 'shortTime' : 'UTC' }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I Have the solution:

```
app.filter('timezone', function(){

 return function (val, offset) {
        if (val != null && val.length > 16) {
    return val.substring(0, 16)
}    
return val;
    };
});
```

template:

```
 <span>{{ date | timezone | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samibel/n4CuQ/