# Is there a way to use angularjs 'date' filter without the the local timezone?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I need to show date in the same timezone as it coming in from service. But angular date filter converts the date to local timezone. is there a way to avoid conversion in local timezone.
My input is 2014-12-11T05:21:22.323-05:00
required output - 12/11/2014 05:21:22 PM (without converting to local timezone)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133776/ignore-time-zone-angularjs

Comment: Thanks Evandro for quick comment. The answer provided in that question shows date time in utc format. I want to preserve original timezone. Please correct if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom filter for this, just convert the desired date without the timezone, for example:

```
myApp.filter('ignoreTimeZone', function(){
  return function(val) {
      var newDate = new Date(val.replace('T', ' ').slice(0, -6));
     return newDate;
  };
});
```

Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ghxd6nom/

You can also use a library for this, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks Evandro. It is working in chrome. But it is not working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides service '$filter'. We can inject this service on controller.

with the help of this service, we can format the date .

```
var dateFrom = $filter('date')(new Date(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

in this way, we can able to format the date with or without Timezone.

The return valus is string and we can convert the string into DateTime on Backend.

The otherway is to use library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).
This library provides better way of converting/formatting Dates.

check this [blog](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html) , which provides angular date/time filtering & formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
$filter('date')(date, format, '+0000')
```

**Documentation**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date