# AngularJS date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

I'm unable to format the date using AngularJS inbuilt filter. I'm getting date-time strings in date object as:

```
{
    'from_date' : '2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z'
    'to_date': '2016-10-31T23:59:59.999Z'
}
```

I'm using the following code in HTML

```
<span class="from-date">{{date.from_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
<span class="to-date">{{date.to_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
```

Currently I'm getting '10/01/2016' and '11/01/2016' respectively. I want the dates to be shown as '10/01/2016' and '10/31/2016' respectively.

Comment: **I guess You aren't caring about timezone when you are saving date into DB.**If you look at your dates and what anguar filter are doing, Its correct. You have to make sure that date returned from the server should be in correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

as your end date is pretty close to 11/01, I assume you will stay with the effect, unless you pipe your dates through a custom filter that strips off the time.

A regex filter will probably be a good choice to capture only the date.

Are you sure to get exactly this date format all the time?

If so,

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,3})?Z$
```

will get you the date in the first capture group

Comment: No, I'm not sure the date objects will always come like that.

Comment: you can also try @Ilan Frumer approach from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133776/ignore-time-zone-angularjs to first make the time reported "free of timezone"

Answer (score 0):

http://momentjs.com/

Moment.js may  help your  problem. It can mask any kind of  date format  by using that  library. You can create  a function   in controller  uses the library , then  you call it  in  filter